# How can helper function render a template manually, and echo it

Tags: cakephp-3.0, helper

I have a Helper as the following:

```
 class IconHelper extends Helper{

     public function showList(){
         //render a template from ctp file
         $template = loadFromTemplate('path/to/my.ctp');
     }
 }
```

I want a function to render a .ctp template and return it .

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried to catch the view class, that may be a start point ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `View Cells`:

In the case that your content can is small inline template, then you can use the **Helper**, as following:

```
 class IconHelper extends Helper{

 public function show($icon){

    $template = '<a class="btn btn-default">'.$icon.'</a>';

    return $template
 }
```

**but** in the case when the content is saved in a template **CTP file**, the best practice is to use the View Cells:

```
 //helper class
 class IconListCell extends Cell{
 public function display($icon){
      //script .....
       $this->set(copmat('icon));
   }
 }
 //file: src/Template/Cell/show.ctp
 <a class="btn btn-default" style="font-size: 40px;width: 70px;">
     <span class="'.$icon.'" id="icon-value-button" data-pack="default">/span>
 </a>
```